# Make the file colon expected

Tags: compiler-construction, makefile, syntax-error

I want to make a compiler for cool language and I have a Makefile:

```
FFLAGS=
BFLAGS=-d -v -y 
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -Wno-write-strings -I /usr/local/boost_1_50_0

FLEX=flex
BISON=bison
CC=g++

SRCS=y.tab.c ast.cpp tokentable.cpp symboltable.cpp main.cpp lex.yy.c semanticanalyzer.cpp astnodevisitor.cpp constants.cpp astnodetypechecker.cpp utility.cpp astnodecodegenerator.cpp
OBJS=y.tab.o ast.o tokentable.o symboltable.o main.o lex.yy.o semanticanalyzer.o astnodevisitor.o constants.o astnodetypechecker.o utility.o astnodecodegenerator.o

cooc : ${OBJS} 
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ ${OBJS}

%.o : %.cpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<

y.tab.c : cool.y
    ${BISON} ${BFLAGS} cool.y

lex.yy.c : cool.flex
    ${FLEX} ${FFLAGS} cool.flex

.depend: ${SRCS} 
    rm -f ./.depend
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -MM $^>>./.depend

include .depend
```

But when I run it in cmd I got these errors that in this part "rm -f ./.depend" colon is expected and last 3 lines have syntax error. Please help me fix the problem.

Comment: you are using tabs, not spaces in recipes, yeah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get errors, please post the exact error text (and useful surrounding context).  Please do no paraphrase error messages.  The exact phrasing, punctuation, etc. in an error message is often critical.  Also provide the type of system and version of software (make, in this case).  For example I know of nothing in GNU make (at least) that will show an error like "colon is expected".

However, I would guess that you've indented your recipe lines (`rm -f ...` etc.) with spaces.  The first character on each recipe line must be an actual TAB character.

I don't know why the `include` line would have a syntax error.  Again if you show the actual error text we could be more helpful.

Comment: MAKE Version 5.0 Copyright <c> 1987,1997 Borland International         Error makefile 25: Colon expected                                         Error makefile 26: Command syntax error                                     Error makefile 27: Command syntax error                                   Error makefile 29: Command syntax error                                        *** 4 errorrs during make ***

Comment: Well, the makefile you're looking at seems to be a GNU make makefile and appears to be written to run on a UNIX system.  I don't know what syntax Borland make supports, and I seriously doubt that makefile will work on Windows anyway.  So, unless the package has Windows support or you're willing to add it, you're out of luck.

Comment: can i make an equal file for windows? is there anyway?

Comment: Sure: it's just code.  There are ports of GNU make that will run on Windows (ask google) that will run that makefile directly.  Finding a way to run make on Windows is only the first step: you need to get a compiler and change the makefile so it can find your compiler and run it properly.  Depending on how the code is written it may or may not be portable to Windows as-is; if not you'll have to change the code to add Windows-specific content.  This is not a task appropriate for StackOverflow.  You need to ask on a mailing list or forum dedicated to the software you're trying to build.